# No fips and --with-fipsdir arguments in OpenSSL 1.0.0l configure script

Tags: linux, openssl, configure, fips

I noticed in trying to build OpenSSL 1.0.0l that, Configure doesn't accept the fips and --with-fipsdir= arguments. But, the OpenSSl 1.0.1f and OpenSSL 0.9.8y accepts the same.

Does that mean that the OpenSSL 1.0.0l wont support fips mode ? is the branch OpenSSL 1.0.0 still under fips validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that the OpenSSL 1.0.0l wont support fips mode ? is the branch OpenSSL 1.0.0 still under fips validation ?

I don't believe 1.0.0 was ever validated. Or if it was, it was a private label validation.

From the [OpenSSL FIPS User Guide 1.2](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-1.2.pdf) (page 9 of 79):

> The FIPS Object Module provides an API for invocation of FIPS approved
>   cryptographic functions from calling applications, and is designed for
>   use in conjunction with standard OpenSSL 0.9.8 distributions beginning
>   with 0.9.8j. Note: OpenSSL 1.0.0 is not supported for use with the
>   OpenSSL FIPS Object Module. These standard OpenSSL 0.9.8 source
>   distributions support the original non-FIPS API as well as a FIPS mode
>   in which the FIPS approved algorithms are implemented by the FIPS
>   Object Module and non-FIPS approved algorithms other than DH are
>   disabled by default. These non-validated algorithms include, but are
>   not limited to, Blowfish, CAST, IDEA, RC-family, and non-SHA message
>   digest and other algorithms.

Comment: I have raised this question in openssl-dev@openssl.org and one of the developer answered that, OpenSSl 1.0.0 series does not support FIPS officially.
Its the FIPS object module which is FIPS validated not the OpenSSL itself.

Comment: @user2927653 - its good to know the OpenSSL docs are correct :) You should accept the answer above so others visiting this page knows the answer is correct and they can use it in their work.

Comment: Yes, I was just making it simpler so that newbies ( like myself ) could understand easily.

Comment: But you are right - the OpenSSL Library (openssl-1.0.0x.tar.gz) is not validated. The FIPS Object Module (openssl-fips-1.2.x.tar.gz) is validated. However, the there are FIPS Capable OpenSSL Libraries, such as 0.9.8 and 1.0.1, and they get paired with the FIPS Object Module.